# Get python Pandas to extract tag value from Azure Cost export (csv)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I hardly know anything about python, let alone pandas module and i need your help.
I have a big csv file, export from multiple tenants from Azure, 2.5GB big, with 2,9M lines from which i have to extract the costs for each exported tag's value. So I have the following table:

| Quantity | EffectivePrice | CostInBillingCurrency | CostCenter | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00003 | 4.409864139 | 0.000000416543726 | UK4435 | "Azure-CostCenter": "1000-UK66453" |
| 0.032256 | 4.409864139 | 0.142244577652554 | UK4435 | "Azure-CostCenter": "CC" |
| 0.032256 | 0.006899978 | 0.142244577652554 | UK4435 | "Azure-CostCenter": "1000-DE775643 " |
| 0.000345502 | 0.00024763 | 0.00000024093395 | UK4435 | "OWNER": "COMPANY","SET": "55436" |
| 0.0291 | 0.044014859 | 0.000007206029143 | UK4435 | "Environment": "DEV" |
| 0.0146 | 0.044014859 | 0.000009507209634 | UK4435 | "Component": "drawn","Team": "ITDesk" |
| 0.001068655 | 0.006899978 | 0.003241156 | UK4435 | "owner": "xxxxx.xxxx@domain.com" |
| 0.000134666 | 0.006949703 | 0.166799481 | UK4435 | "Azure-CostCenter": "CC" |
| 24 | 0.006949703 | 0.166799481 | UK4435 | "Azure-CostCenter": "1000-UK66453" |

I've added a bigger table because I would like to emphasize the different colums and different `value:key` pairs from the `Tags` column. Also added additional column to somehow place the two colums I'm interested in. They are irrelevant

Now, I would like to correlate data from the `CostInBillingCurrency` column with the `Tags` column, based on the value of each `Azure-CostCenter`'s tag value, which in my case would be: `1000-UK66453`, `CC`, `1000-DE775643` and so on and only for the tag `Azure-CostCenter`. I don't care about the rest because, at some point this tag will be everywhere and thus the script will work across the whole CSV file.
The expected result would be:

| Tag | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1000-UK66453 | 24.00003 |
| CC | 0.032390666 |
| 1000-DE775643 | 0.032256 |
| N/A | 0.001068655 |

Value from first row is the sum of all rows from `CostInBillingCurrency` that correspond to the tag value of `1000-UK66453` and so on. - exported into a new `CSV` file.
`N/A` is the sum of all tags that don't have the key of `Azure-CostCenter` and have anything else.

What i did so far, based on my research is:

```
import pandas as pd
bill = pd.read_csv("Costs.csv", low_memory=False)
subsdata = bill(index_col=0, usecols={
    'Tags': str, 'CostInBillingCurrency': str})
```

and to export

```
xxxxxxxx.to_csv("consolidation.csv", index=True)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this scenario (created by a friend):

```
from csv import DictReader

cost_center_spent_dict = {}
const_cost_center_name = '"Azure-CostCenter"'
with open('file_path.csv', 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        tags = row['Tags']
        if const_cost_center_name in tags:
            parsed_tags = tags.split(',')
            for tag in parsed_tags:
                if const_cost_center_name in tag:
                    (key, cost_center)= tag.split(':')
            costs = float(row['CostInBillingCurrency'])
            if cost_center in cost_center_spent_dict:
                cost_center_spent_dict[cost_center] = cost_center_spent_dict[cost_center] + costs
            else:
                cost_center_spent_dict[cost_center] = costs

print(cost_center_spent_dict)

with open('file_path_out.csv', 'w' , encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as output:
    output.write("Cost Center, Amount\n")
    for key in cost_center_spent_dict.keys():
        output.write("%s, %s\n" % (key, cost_center_spent_dict[key]))
```